# how to capture the Hardware BackKey click event when onscreen keyboard is present

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, on-screen-keyboard

I am developing Windows Phone 8 PhoneGap app. When the onscreen keyboard is present, if we click the hardware back key, it closes the onscreen keyboard. But at that time no event is getting fired including BackKeyPress event. May I know how to capture the Hardware BackKey click event when onscreen keyboard is present?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a easy way to do this, but you could listen to the TextBox.LostFocus event to know when the keyboard is hidden.

If you have more than one textbox, check if the others didn't get the focus.

Comment: even LostFocus event is not getting fired when we are pressing the hardware back button.

Comment: The event gets fired for me, but the solution is a bit dangerous if you're using it to find out if the back button is pressed. The TextBox could lose focus for a number of other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If i am right you want to catch the event fired when user presses back key on the phone, then you can override the event for the same

```
    protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnBackKeyPress(e);

        //your logic goes here
    }
```

If you press the key When the on screen keyboard is present the default behavior is to close the keyboard, you can only catch this event once the keyboard is closed.

If you want to detect the closing of the keyboard you can use the LostFocus event of the textbox or any other similar control that you might be using. hope this helps!

Comment: The issue is this event is not getting fired when clicking hardware back key while onscreen keyboard is present.